# Deactivate components until an element is selected from JComboBox

Tags: java, mysql, swing, foreign-keys, jcombobox

I am working on Java swing application using data base with MySQL

I need to know if I can deactivate components until select an element from `JComboBox`? I must know the choice of the 1st jcombobox to fill the 2nd `JComboBox`; the 1st choice is a foreign key on the 2nd, like that :

```
ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT NomF FROM famille_de_type");
while (res.next()) {
    comboBox_Fam_innewT.addItem(res.getString(1));                
}
```

this is my example :

[image: example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you can.  When you start work call `setEnabled(false)` to second comboBox. And add to 1st combobox `ItemListener`. It will be listen item selection.

```
firstComboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener()
    {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED)
            {
                Object selectedItem = e.getItem(); // new item selected
                // TODO select values for 2nd combobox
                // TODO fill 2nd combobox
                secondComboBox.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to know if i can deactivate components until select an element from jcombobox ?

YES. Why not Component.[SetEnabled(false)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29)?

Also you might want to look at [ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html) interface to achieve your goal. Here is more about [Handling Events on a Combo Box.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#listeners)

Answer (score 1):

So in the `ActionListenr` of the `JComboBox`, simply call the `setEnabled` methods, passing `false` to disable them, or `true` to enable them